# Object Factory in golang

Tags: syntax, go, go-interface

I am a new to golang. I need to design a function to create object of differing types based on input. But I failed to figure out how to design the interface. Here comes my code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type AA struct{
    name string
}

func (this *AA) say(){
    fmt.Println("==========>AA")
}
type BB struct{
    *AA
    age int
}
func (this *BB) say(){
    fmt.Println("==========>BB")
}

func ObjectFactory(type int) *AA {
    if type ==1 {
        return new(AA)
    }else{
        return new(BB)
    }
}

func main() {
    obj1 := ObjectFactory(0)
    obj1.say()
    obj2 := ObjectFactory(0)
    obj2.say()
}
```

The compiler tells me error no matter I ask ObjectFactory return *AA or interface{}.  How can I make it work?

Comment: What exact error do you get? What line does the compiler tell you is wrong?

Comment: It might seem as if you are trying to emulate traditional OOP idiom in Go (or force onto). This is not a good idea. You might consider redesigning your solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, using `type` as a variable name is disallowed in go (see the [spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Keywords)). That is your first problem.

The return type of object factory is *AA. This means that it can only return variables of type *AA, which causes the return of type of BB to fail. As defined in the spec, go doesn't have type inheritance, just struct embedding.

If you create an interface called sayer, you can use that instead of *AA in your ObjectFactory function.

```
type sayer interface {
    say()
}
```

You probably want to use this interface when trying to get multiple dispatch (as demonstrated in the code below (see [on play.golang.org](http://play.golang.org/p/NJeSTnzdQl) as well).

Try this code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type sayer interface {
    say()
}

type AA struct{
    name string
}

func (this *AA) say(){
    fmt.Println("==========>AA")
}
type BB struct{
    *AA
    age int
}
func (this *BB) say(){
    fmt.Println("==========>BB")
}

func ObjectFactory(typeNum int) sayer {
    if typeNum ==1 {
        return new(AA)
    }else{
        return new(BB)
    }
}

func main() {
    obj1 := ObjectFactory(1)
    obj1.say()
    obj2 := ObjectFactory(0)
    obj2.say()
}
```

Comment: Just for reference: the [list of reserved keywords](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Keywords) from the spec...

Comment: Thanks for the link. I put in the answer.